# PHP Convert multi level multi-dimensional array to a table

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have searched for some time but I haven't found a good solution to this.  There are similar posts for dealing with 1,2,3 level arrays but none that allows for an unknown level of arrays.

Aim:
Cycle through x levels of multi dimensional arrays:
if
 1. value is array, continue cycle
 2. is not an array close off cycle
and output as a readable table.

I can do this manually by embedding foreach loops but whenever I try to build into a recursive function it melts.

Flat foreach example (which works for the array shown).

```
function doit($ARR){
if( is_array($ARR) )
    {

        foreach($ARR as $K => $ARR2)
            {
                if( is_array($ARR2) )
                    {
                        $t .= '<tr><td> > '.key($ARR).'</td>';
                        foreach($ARR2 as $K2 => $ARR3)
                            {
                                if( is_array($ARR3) )
                                    {
                                        $t .= '</tr><tr><td> >>  '.key($ARR2).'</td>';
                                        foreach($ARR3 as $K3 => $ARR4)
                                            {
                                                if( is_array($ARR4) )
                                                    {
                                                        $t .= '</tr><tr><td> >>> '.key($ARR3).'</td>';
                                                        foreach($ARR4 as $K4 => $ARR5)
                                                            {
                                                                if( is_array($ARR5) )
                                                                    {
                                                                        $t .= '</tr><tr><td> >>>> '.key($ARR4).'</td>';
                                                                        foreach($ARR5 as $K5 => $ARR6)
                                                                            {
                                                                                if( is_array($ARR6) )
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        $t .= '</tr><tr><td> >>>>> '.key($ARR5).'</td>';
                                                                                        foreach($ARR6 as $K6 => $ARR7)
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                if( is_array($ARR7) )
                                                                                                    {
                                                                                                        $t .= '</tr><tr><td> >>>>>> '.key($ARR6).'</td>';
                                                                                                        foreach($ARR7 as $K7 => $ARR8)
                                                                                                            {
                                                                                                                if( is_array($ARR8) )
                                                                                                                    {
                                                                                                                        $t .= '</tr><tr><td> >>>>>>> '.key($ARR7).'</td>';

                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                else
                                                                                                                    {
                                                                                                                        $t .= '<td>'.$ARR8.'</td>';
                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                            }

                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                else
                                                                                                    {
                                                                                                        $t .= '<td>'.$ARR7.'</td>';
                                                                                                    }
                                                                                            }
                                                                                    }
                                                                                else
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        $t .= '<td>'.$ARR6.'</td>';
                                                                                    }
                                                                            }
                                                                    }
                                                                else
                                                                    {
                                                                        $t .= '<td>'.$ARR5.'</td>';
                                                                    }
                                                            }
                                                    }
                                                else
                                                    {
                                                            $t .= '<td>'.$ARR4.'</td>';
                                                    }
                                            }
                                    }
                                else
                                    {
                                        $t .= '<td>'.$ARR3.'</td>';
                                    }
                            }
                    }
                else
                    {
                        $t .= '<td>'.$ARR2.'</td>';
                    }
            }
    }
else
    {
    }
$t .= '</tr>';
return '<table>'.$t.'</table>';
```

}

Example array to populate:

```
$IRS_EX_COVERAGE        =   array(
'Taxable returns:'      =>  array(                  
    'Individual income tax returns, total' => array(        
        'Returns with total positive income under $200,000 :' =>  array(    
            'Nonbusiness returns without Earned Income Tax Credit:' =>  array(
                'Without Schedules C, E, F, or Form 2106' => array(79643929,262610,0.3,32922,229688),   
                'With Schedule E or Form 2106' => array(15997590,107300,0.7,49408,57892)
            ),
            'Business returns without Earned Income Tax Credit:' =>  array(     
                'Nonfarm business returns by size of total gross receipts :' =>  array( 
                    'Under $25,000' => array(10534942,94952,0.9,35192,59760),
                    '$25,000 under $100,000' => array(3124877,74825,2.4,24012,50813),
                    '$100,000 under $200,000' => array(877851,21724,2.5,13681,8043),
                    '$200,000 or more' => array(685163,13684,2.0,11549,2135)
                ),
                'Farm returns' => array(1268251,4255,0.3,2475,1780)
            ),
            'Business and nonbusiness returns with Earned Income' =>  array(        
                'Tax Credit by size of total gross receipts :' =>  array(   
                    'Under $25,000' => array(6502703,459920,1.7,27009,432911),
                    '$25,000 or more' => array(1806228,18112,1.0,11161,6951)
                )
            )
        ),
        'Returns with total positive income of at least $200,000  and under $1,000,000 :' =>  array(            
                'Nonbusiness returns' => array(4068298,71280,1.8,20795,50485),  
                'Business returns' => array(1734110,51151,2.9,17822,33329)
        ),
        'Returns with total positive income of $1,000,000 or more' => array(416178,39753,9.6,13781,25972),          
        'International returns' => array(201097,8551,4.3,7269,1282),    
    )
)
```

);

$PRN_IRS =  doit($IRS_EX_COVERAGE);

An example of the output table is shown here: http://taxformcalculator.com/IRS-audit-calculator.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure why your code reuses the "under 25000" text for the next entries on the same level, even if they have a different key. Here is a recursive function you can use as a starting point.

```
$testdata = array(
'Taxable returns:'      =>  array(                  
    'Individual income tax returns, total' => array(        
        'Returns with total positive income under $200,000 :' =>  array(    
            'Nonbusiness returns without Earned Income Tax Credit:' =>  array(
                'Without Schedules C, E, F, or Form 2106' => array(79643929,262610,0.3,32922,229688),   
                'With Schedule E or Form 2106' => array(15997590,107300,0.7,49408,57892)
            ),
            'Business returns without Earned Income Tax Credit:' =>  array(     
                'Nonfarm business returns by size of total gross receipts :' =>  array( 
                    'Under $25,000' => array(10534942,94952,0.9,35192,59760),
                    '$25,000 under $100,000' => array(3124877,74825,2.4,24012,50813),
                    '$100,000 under $200,000' => array(877851,21724,2.5,13681,8043),
                    '$200,000 or more' => array(685163,13684,2.0,11549,2135)
                ),
                'Farm returns' => array(1268251,4255,0.3,2475,1780)
            ),
            'Business and nonbusiness returns with Earned Income' =>  array(        
                'Tax Credit by size of total gross receipts :' =>  array(   
                    'Under $25,000' => array(6502703,459920,1.7,27009,432911),
                    '$25,000 or more' => array(1806228,18112,1.0,11161,6951)
                )
            )
        ),
        'Returns with total positive income of at least $200,000  and under $1,000,000 :' =>  array(            
                'Nonbusiness returns' => array(4068298,71280,1.8,20795,50485),  
                'Business returns' => array(1734110,51151,2.9,17822,33329)
        ),
        'Returns with total positive income of $1,000,000 or more' => array(416178,39753,9.6,13781,25972),          
        'International returns' => array(201097,8551,4.3,7269,1282),    
    )
));

function doit_recurse($cellname, $arr, $depth = 0) {
    $ret = "";
    if ($depth === 0) {
         $ret .= "<table>";
    }

    $close_tr = "";
    if (!empty($cellname)) {
        $prefix = str_repeat (">", $depth);
        $ret .= "<tr><td> $prefix $cellname</td>";
        $close_tr = "</tr>";
    }
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if (is_numeric($value)) {
            $ret .= "<td>$value</td>";
        } else {
            $ret .= $close_tr . doit_recurse($key, $value, $depth + 1);
        }
    }

    if ($depth === 0) {
         $ret .= "</tr></table>";
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

var_dump(doit_recurse('', $testdata));

here is the old and new output

old

```
string(2222) "<table><tr><td> > Taxable returns:</td></tr><tr><td> >>  Individual income tax returns, total</td></tr><tr><td> >>> Returns with total positive income under $200,000 :</td></tr><tr><td> >>>> Nonbusiness returns without Earned Income Tax Credit:</td></tr><tr><td> >>>>> Without Schedules C, E, F, or Form 2106</td><td>79643929</td><td>262610</td><td>0.3</td><td>32922</td><td>229688</td></tr><tr><td> >>>>> Without Schedules C, E, F, or Form 2106</td><td>15997590</td><td>107300</td><td>0.7</td><td>49408</td><td>57892</td></tr><tr><td> >>>> Nonbusiness returns without Earned Income Tax Credit:</td></tr><tr><td> >>>>> Nonfarm business returns by size of total gross receipts :</td></tr><tr><td> >>>>>> Under $25,000</td><td>10534942</td><td>94952</td><td>0.9</td><td>35192</td><td>59760</td></tr><tr><td> >>>>>> Under $25,000</td><td>3124877</td><td>74825</td><td>2.4</td><td>24012</td><td>50813</td></tr><tr><td> >>>>>> Under $25,000</td><td>877851</td><td>21724</td><td>2.5</td><td>13681</td><td>8043</td></tr><tr><td> >>>>>> Under $25,000</td><td>685163</td><td>13684</td><td>2</td><td>11549</td><td>2135</td></tr><tr><td> >>>>> Nonfarm business returns by size of total gross receipts :</td><td>1268251</td><td>4255</td><td>0.3</td><td>2475</td><td>1780</td></tr><tr><td> >>>> Nonbusiness returns without Earned Income Tax Credit:</td></tr><tr><td> >>>>> Tax Credit by size of total gross receipts :</td></tr><tr><td> >>>>>> Under $25,000</td><td>6502703</td><td>459920</td><td>1.7</td><td>27009</td><td>432911</td></tr><tr><td> >>>>>> Under $25,000</td><td>1806228</td><td>18112</td><td>1</td><td>11161</td><td>6951</td></tr><tr><td> >>> Returns with total positive income under $200,000 :</td></tr><tr><td> >>>> Nonbusiness returns</td><td>4068298</td><td>71280</td><td>1.8</td><td>20795</td><td>50485</td></tr><tr><td> >>>> Nonbusiness returns</td><td>1734110</td><td>51151</td><td>2.9</td><td>17822</td><td>33329</td></tr><tr><td> >>> Returns with total positive income under $200,000 :</td><td>416178</td><td>39753</td><td>9.6</td><td>13781</td><td>25972</td></tr><tr><td> >>> Returns with total positive income under $200,000 :</td><td>201097</td><td>8551</td><td>4.3</td><td>7269</td><td>1282</td></tr></table>"
```

new

```
string(2178) "<table><tr><td> > Taxable returns:</td></tr><tr><td> >> Individual income tax returns, total</td></tr><tr><td> >>> Returns with total positive income under $200,000 :</td></tr><tr><td> >>>> Nonbusiness returns without Earned Income Tax Credit:</td></tr><tr><td> >>>>> Without Schedules C, E, F, or Form 2106</td><td>79643929</td><td>262610</td><td>0.3</td><td>32922</td><td>229688</td></tr><tr><td> >>>>> With Schedule E or Form 2106</td><td>15997590</td><td>107300</td><td>0.7</td><td>49408</td><td>57892</td></tr><tr><td> >>>> Business returns without Earned Income Tax Credit:</td></tr><tr><td> >>>>> Nonfarm business returns by size of total gross receipts :</td></tr><tr><td> >>>>>> Under $25,000</td><td>10534942</td><td>94952</td><td>0.9</td><td>35192</td><td>59760</td></tr><tr><td> >>>>>> $25,000 under $100,000</td><td>3124877</td><td>74825</td><td>2.4</td><td>24012</td><td>50813</td></tr><tr><td> >>>>>> $100,000 under $200,000</td><td>877851</td><td>21724</td><td>2.5</td><td>13681</td><td>8043</td></tr><tr><td> >>>>>> $200,000 or more</td><td>685163</td><td>13684</td><td>2</td><td>11549</td><td>2135</td></tr><tr><td> >>>>> Farm returns</td><td>1268251</td><td>4255</td><td>0.3</td><td>2475</td><td>1780</td></tr><tr><td> >>>> Business and nonbusiness returns with Earned Income</td></tr><tr><td> >>>>> Tax Credit by size of total gross receipts :</td></tr><tr><td> >>>>>> Under $25,000</td><td>6502703</td><td>459920</td><td>1.7</td><td>27009</td><td>432911</td></tr><tr><td> >>>>>> $25,000 or more</td><td>1806228</td><td>18112</td><td>1</td><td>11161</td><td>6951</td></tr><tr><td> >>> Returns with total positive income of at least $200,000  and under $1,000,000 :</td></tr><tr><td> >>>> Nonbusiness returns</td><td>4068298</td><td>71280</td><td>1.8</td><td>20795</td><td>50485</td></tr><tr><td> >>>> Business returns</td><td>1734110</td><td>51151</td><td>2.9</td><td>17822</td><td>33329</td></tr><tr><td> >>> Returns with total positive income of $1,000,000 or more</td><td>416178</td><td>39753</td><td>9.6</td><td>13781</td><td>25972</td></tr><tr><td> >>> International returns</td><td>201097</td><td>8551</td><td>4.3</td><td>7269</td><td>1282</td></tr></table>"
```

if you want the same result as in your example, use

```
function doit_recurse($cellname, $arr, $depth = 0) {
    $ret = "";
    if ($depth === 0) {
         $ret .= "<table>";
    }

    $close_tr = "";
    if (!empty($cellname)) {
        $prefix = str_repeat (">", $depth);
        $ret .= "<tr><td> $prefix $cellname</td>";
        $close_tr = "</tr>";
    }
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if (is_numeric($value)) {
            $ret .= "<td>$value</td>";
        } else {
            $ret .= $close_tr . doit_recurse(array_keys($arr)[0], $value, $depth + 1);
        }
    }

    if ($depth === 0) {
         $ret .= "</tr></table>";
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you malms, that was perfect.  I came so close to that solution several times but kept tripping myself up.

For other who may find this, here is the final solution I used.

Note that what I wanted was to apply scaled shading via css and put leading symbols ahead of each table header subset.  As malms correctly pointed out all the header should be different (see $25k question from malms).

This is how I ended up:

```
function doit_recurse($cellname, $arr, $maxdepth = 0, $depth = 0, $caption ) {
$ret = "";
if ($depth === 0) {
     $ret .= "<table class=\"tableData\"><caption>$caption</caption>";
}
$sym        = array('', '','&#9654;','&#9655;','&#9659;','&#9657;','&#8729;');
$close_tr   = "";
$tddata     = "";
$tdspan     = 0;
$thclass    = "";
if (!empty($cellname)) {
    $thclass    = "class=\"nTH$depth\"";
    $tdcontent  = $sym[$depth]." ".$cellname." ".$depth;
    $close_tr   = "</tr>";
}
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (is_numeric($value)) {
        $tddata .= "<td>$value</td>";
    } else {
        $tdspan     = $maxdepth;
        $tddata .= $close_tr . doit_recurse($key, $value, $maxdepth, $depth + 1);
    }
}

$ret .= "<tr><th $thclass colspan=\"$tdspan\">$tdcontent</th>$tddata";

if ($depth === 0) {
     $ret .= "</tr></table>";
}
return $ret;
```

}

```
$PRN_IRS =  doit_recurse('', $IRS_EX_COVERAGE, 6, 0, 'Caption name here');
```

As you will see I also added in a caption for the table.

I wanted this approach so that I can build the html table and also build JavaScript arrays for dynamic select options (not shown but obvious how to build).

Live [example here](http://taxformcalculator.com/IRS-audit-calculator.html) for those who are looking for anything similar.  Thank again malms, that was awesome.  I had really gone down the rabbit hole on that one :)